# Is Javascript's workers the same as threads?

Tags: javascript, web-worker

I wanted to know if workers in JS are the same as threads? Is there really parallelism or it's just context switching?

Comment: Well threads can involve context switching too.

Comment: It depends on the implementation (and the number of used cores)

Comment: Why do you ask? It doesn't really matter (cannot cause problems) since webworkers cannot share memory.

Answer (score 1):

**Web Workers** is basically an HTML5 API that runs a named JavaScript file, which contains the code that will run in the worker thread. Web Workers provide a facility for creating new threads that can execute scripts concurrently, thus creating a multi threaded architecture in which the browser can accomplish multiple tasks asynchronously.